# How to set font in Wordpress in Custom CSS section?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, amazon-lightsail

Running Wordpress with AWS Lightsail. This is the location of the uploaded font. I would use it for certain text.

[image]

Tried this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url(/icons.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and this to define:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url(/et-fonts/icons.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

none worked. What is wrong?

This is which I would apply for:

```
<span
  style={{ fontFamily: "Icons", fontSize: "2rem", cursor: "pointer" }}
>
  c
</span>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is it:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url(/wp-content/uploads/et-fonts/icons.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this.

theme folder >> font folder >> font.ttf

Please just remove first "/" in url.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url(/et-fonts/icons.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

change to

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url(et-fonts/icons.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```